# jQuery selector first matches in a set of elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How do I select the first matches for a given selector over a set of elements?

For example, suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li class="interesting">red</li> 
<li class="interesting">yellow</li> 
<li class="interesting">blue</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>eggs</li>
<li>spam</li>
<li class="interesting">circle</li> 
<li class="interesting">square</li> 
<li class="interesting">triangle</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>tofu</li>
<li>bacon</li>
<li class="interesting">circle</li> 
<li class="interesting">square</li> 
<li class="interesting">triangle</li>
</ul>
```

I want the selector that retrieves the *first* `.interesting` element for each `ul`.

So in this case:

```
$("ul .interesting:magic-selector");
```

Would match the following:

```
<li class="interesting">one</li> 
<li class="interesting">red</li> 
<li class="interesting">circle</li>
```

### After trying out first-child (was Hmmmm...)

I'm trying the `:first-child` selector and it doesn't seem to work, at least not in Chrome.

Here's some sample code:

```
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li class="interesting">red</li> 
<li class="interesting">yellow</li> 
<li class="interesting">blue</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>eggs</li>
<li>spam</li>
<li class="interesting">circle</li> 
<li class="interesting">square</li> 
<li class="interesting">triangle</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>tofu</li>
<li>bacon</li>
<li class="interesting">circle</li> 
<li class="interesting">square</li> 
<li class="interesting">triangle</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul .interesting:first-child").css('color', 'red'); // nothing happens
            // maybe I have the order wrong? only:
        $("ul .interesting :first-child").css('color', 'orange'); // nothing happens
        $("ul :first-child.interesting ").css('color', 'yellow'); // nothing happens
        $("ul :first-child .interesting ").css('color', 'green'); // nothing happens
        $("ul :first-child").css('color', 'gray'); // the control; it turns foo, eggs, and tofu gray
    });
</script>
```

Looks like maybe `first-child` only works to select the first child of a parent element, not the first matching selector of a parent element.

Barring that, I suppose I will have to do something like:

```
$("ul").each(function () {
    $(this).find(".interesting:first")…
});
```

Comment: You won't need `each`, something like http://jsfiddle.net/uAmN2/ will do. But I don't think there is any `:magic-selector` that does this. The CSS equivalent would be `:first-of-type`

Answer (score 3):

`:first-child` <-- try that `magic-selector` on for size.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, at least not for this kind of selector. :(

Comment: This is dead wrong, because `:first-child` only matches (guess what) the first child. So if `li.interesting` is not the first child, `:first-child` will not match. The corresponding CSS3 selector is actually `:first-of-type`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the first-child selector.
http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul .interesting:first")
```

should do the trick

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That only gets the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```
:first-child
```

That'll be the magic selector you're looking for

Edit:  beaten to it!